# Number of sequences with repeating numbers - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There is a set of $N$ integers: $\left\{1,2,...,N\right\}$. We are considering all possible sequences of length $n=4$, created using the numbers from the set. The total number of sequences is $N^n=N^4$. It is easy to see that the sequences can be divided into 4 groups:

1) Sequence where all numbers are the same. There are $N$ of these sequences.

2) Sequence where all numbers are different. There are $\frac{N!}{(N-4)!}$ of these sequenes.

3) Sequences where exactly two numbers are the same (it includes the case when this happens twice in a sequence).

4) Sequences where exactly three numbers are the same.

The question is: what is the number of sequences in groups 3) and 4)?

Clearly, the total number of sequences needs to add up to $N^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For case 3) do you count outcomes like 1122?  Or only outcomes like 1123?  When generalizing to higher $n$ you need to be careful.

As for counting outcomes where exactly three distinct numbers appear... so sequences like $1123$ or $3112$ etc... choose the positions of the repeated number in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.  Pick which number it was that was repeated in $N$ ways.  For the left-most remaining position, pick which number it was in $N-1$ ways.  Finally for the final remaining position, pick which number it was in $N-2$ ways.  This gives $\binom{4}{2}\cdot N\cdot (N-1)\cdot (N-2)$.

As for counting outcomes where exactly two distinct numbers appear, both of which being repeated... so sequences like $1122$ or $1221$ etc... this can fool many people.  Here are two ways you can think of it.  You can first pick the two numbers that appear in $\binom{N}{2}$ ways.  You can then choose which positions are occupied specifically by the *smaller* of the numbers chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, letting the remaining positions be occupied by the other number.  This gives a total of $\binom{N}{2}\binom{4}{2}$.  Alternatively, you could pick what number appeared in the first position in $N$ ways.  Then, you can pick which other position matched the first position in $3$ ways.  You can then fill the remaining two positions with another number in $N-1$ ways giving a total of $3N(N-1)$ which you can check is equal to what we had before just written in a different way.

For sequences where one number occurs three times and another different number occurred once, so sequences like $1112$ or $1211$ etc... pick the position of the singleton and what number it was.  Then pick the remaining number.  This gives a total of $4N(N-1)$

---

Generalizing this to larger $n$, one of the easiest generalizations that can be made is to talk about the number of distinct digits who appeared but make no mention of how exactly they are partitioned... so sequences like $112233$, $122333$ and $123333$ all count as being in the same category, that of having three distinct numbers occurring.

For this, there are $\left\{\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right\}\cdot N\frac{k}{~}$ such sequences with $k$ distinct numbers occurring where $\left\{\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right\}$ is the [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and $N\frac{k}{~}$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

You do indeed have $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left\{\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right\}\cdot N\frac{k}{~}=N^n$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was thinking of these two cases combined, so you can have both 3 distinct numbers and 2 distinct numbers in a sequence. Right before you answered, I had realized how to find the number of sequences for the case when one number occurs three times and another different number occurs once (result $4N(N-1)$, just as you pointed out). Then I just calculated $N^4-N-\frac{N!}{(N-4)!}-4N(N-1)$ to get the last result (group 3 in my question). Thanks once again for great explanations!